# Is it possible to ignore a certain index in a list?

Tags: python

For example:

```
list = [A, B, C]
rand = random.randrange(0, len(list)
return list[rand]
```

I want to return anything but 'B', so index 1.

Comment: Remove `B` from the list, *then* pick a random item…?

Comment: You can remove `B` from `list`, or copy all the members of `list` that are not `B` to a new list. Also, the word `list` in python is reserved, so it's best you chose a different name for that list.

Comment: The problem is the list stays the same length in my program so if it returns B I get an Index Error. I can't change the length of it.

Comment: Thanks, but it was just an example so you can ignore the names

Comment: What do you mean by "the list stays the same length" - why cant you create `list` by `list1 = [x for x in list if x != 'B']` and then use `list1`?

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: Please don't attempt to fix code in a question like that. Do it in an answer or mention it in a comment.

Comment: @martineau I did it because [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/843953) says to fix syntax/typos if you're sure it's not relevant to the question. The missing parenthesis and `list` -> `lst` isn't relevant to OP's question, which asks how to prevent `random.randrange()` from returning a particular index.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Adding the missing parenthesis would have been fine, though extremely insignificant. Using `list`, while not recommended, is perfectly legit—and isn't on that Do list.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case I would either do:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
random.choice([i for i in a if not i == 'b'])
```

Or:

```
random.choice([val for i, val in enumerate(a) if not i == 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one index to exclude, you can use random.choice() on the remainder of the list (e.g. assembled using subscripts):

```
import random

L = ['A', 'B', 'C']
i = 1
r = random.choice(L[:i]+L[i+1:]) # 'A'
```

If you have multiple indexes to exclude, you can randomly select an index from the set of indexes where the exclusions are removed:

```
L = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
exclude = {1,3,4}

i,*_ = random.sample({*range(len(L))}-exclude,1)
r = L[i] # 'C'
```